# dwmblocks bluetooth module. how to show connected device name?

Tags: linux, bash, bluetooth, dwm, tiling-wm

im using **DWM** with `dwmblocks` for the statusbar, i have serveral modules/scritps running for the status including bluetooth script that wrote to show some info and status if a device is connected

```
 #!/bin/bash
  
  case $BLOCK_BUTTON in
          1) setsid -f blueman-manager ;;
          2) notify-send "$icon Device Connected" "$(if [[ "$(bluetoothctl info)" != "Missing device address argument" ]]; then 
                                                  echo= "$(bluetoothctl info | grep "Name" | awk '{print $2}')"
else
                                                  echo= "No Device Connected" )" ;;
          3) notify-send "$icon  Bluetooth" "\- Show Bluetooth Status.
  - Click to open Bluetooth Manager.
  - Middle click to show Connected Devices." ;;
  
  esac
  
    if [[ "$(bluetoothctl info)" != "Missing device address argument" ]]; then
      icon="  "
    else
      icon="  "
    fi
  
  printf "%s%s\\n" "$icon"
```

the script works fine but the middle click action

```
2) notify-send "$icon Device Connected" "$(if [[ "$(bluetoothctl info)" != "Missing device address argument" ]]; then 
                                                  echo= "$(bluetoothctl info | grep "Name" | awk '{print $2}')"
else
                                                  echo= "No Device Connected" )" ;;
```

doesn't show anything, i only want it to shows "Device Connected - (name of the device)" when a device is a connected else it shows "No Device Connected", but click action doesn't seems to work it doesn't even show a blank notification.

Comment: i got it working.

Comment: would you like to share how did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

**For any one who had a problem**

```
 #!/bin/sh
  case $BLOCK_BUTTON in
          1) setsid -f blueman-manager ;;
          2) notify-send "$icon Device Connected" "$(if [ "$(bluetoothctl info)" != "Missing device address argument" ]; then
                                                  echo= bluetoothctl info | grep "Name" | awk '{print $2}'
        else
            echo 'No Device Connected'
                          fi )" ;;
          3) notify-send "$icon  Bluetooth" "\- Show Bluetooth Status.
  - Click to open Bluetooth Manager.
  - Middle click to show Connected Devices." ;;

  esac

    if [ "$(bluetoothctl info)" != "Missing device address argument" ]; then
      icon="  "
    else
      icon="  "
    fi

  printf "%s\\n" "$icon"
```

Here  is what i  changed.

```
2) notify-send "$icon Device Connected" "$(if [ "$(bluetoothctl info)" != "Missing device address argument" ]; then
                                                      echo= bluetoothctl info | grep "Name" | awk '{print $2}'
            else
                echo 'No Device Connected'
                              fi )" ;;
```

1. The IF statement was not closed i closed it
2. When the first argument meet the requirement which is "does not equal "Missing device address argument"" echo will run as command substitution and it will fail
3. When no device is connected echo will run as command substitution and it will fail. and we want it to just echo that there are no device connected.

For more information check this resource
(https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2091)

```bsh
    printf "%s\\n" "$icon"
```

The oraginal script supplied 2 strings but only was passed

Comment: Can you also explain what you did differently to fix this?

Comment: I don't understand - please edit these details into the answer